# possible unstability of python 3 intepretor

Tags: python

Hey I'm writing because I ran into a problem that I can't track down myself.

I'm trying to load some data in from a huge csv file (27.3 GB) which can be found here https://github.com/several27/FakeNewsCorpus, but every time i try to run the code below, I get a KeyError 'content' at row 116454. As far as I understand this should be because the 'content' field isn't set in the obj variable, but it should be. Where the fault happens are consistent with every run.

It doesn't only fail at this row, this is just the first row where it fails. It does work correctly on other rows since the length of words aren't zero. I have tried to alter the maximum size of the csv field to 2000000000 since this also has been a problem. I'm running it in jupiter notebook, the 'count' variable is only for tracking the error.

Codesnip

```
def get_words(text) :
        regex = re.compile(r"\w+\'\w+|\w+|\,|\.")
        return set(re.findall(regex, text))

words = set()
count = 0

with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline= '') as articles:
    reader = csv.reader(articles)
    hds = next(reader, None) 

    print(hds)

    for row in reader:
        obj = {}
        for hd, val in zip(hds, row):
            obj[hd] = val

        ws, _ = find_urls(lowercase(obj['content'])) <- error here
        ws = get_words(ws)

        words = words | ws
        count = count + 1
    try:
        words.remove('URL')
    except:
        pass
```

The find_url and lowercase funktion just take a string as an input and return a altered string. they have been tested.

I'm running this on a asus laptop with an i7 intel CPU and 16 GB ram just to mention that too. the harddrive the csv file is on are a samsung SSD, and it is under a year old so there should not be any faulty pages on it yet. the csv file contains articles and the content field should never be emtpy since this will be the same as saying that the article has no content.

Comment: Did you try to dump failed data line? Could it be that data is broken in this row? When Python doesn't have memory or there is problem with segmentation it crashes with appropriate message. It doesn't look like problem with Python.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that multiline fields in a CSV file can throw off the parser if the correct `quotechar` isn't specified upon creation of the `reader` object. Especially in non-US CSV files, non-default separators and quotechars can often be found.

Comment: Can you try and reduce the problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't rely on us downloading 27 GB of data?

Comment: no but can say that it disapatired when i split the file into small files. so my guess would be that the csv lib isn't made for huge files and that the buffer most likely are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark without getting a look at your data (especially the rows around your infamous #116454), but `zip()` stops as soon as one of the iterators is exhausted. Try

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```

and replace the lines

```
    for hd, val in zip(hds, row):
        obj[hd] = val
```

with

```
    for hd, val in zip_longest(hds, row, fillvalue=''):
        obj[hd] = val
```

and see what happens. Also, read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Comment: Or perhaps the OP could use `csv.DictReader` and avoid the zipping?

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Right, that's even better. I'd upvote that answer in a flash :)

Comment: The row has the content part in it as i said. that goes for every row that cause an error. but thanks will try that